# Installing SoapySdr modules for RTL-SDR or AirSpy

Tags: ubuntu, rtl-sdr

I am trying to build and run the simple example for SoapySdr as found here https://github.com/pothosware/SoapySDR/wiki/C_API_Example. I can use the SDR with Gnuradio but that doesn't work for my application (reason not relevant). I get the simple program to compile but when it runs it doesn't see any devices.
Running

```
SoapySDRUtil --info

    ######################################################
    ##     Soapy SDR -- the SDR abstraction library     ##
    ######################################################

Lib Version: v0.8.1-gbb33b2d2
API Version: v0.8.200
ABI Version: v0.8-3
Install root: /usr/local
Search path:  /usr/local/lib/SoapySDR/modules0.8-3 (missing)
No modules found!
Available factories... No factories found!
Available converters...
 -  CF32 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]...
```

No modules found and no factories found. For me the hard part is getting a time series stream from the device. I can do whatever processing I need on that stream.
So, I just need to get this simple example to run.
I've tried a number of installs such as
    `sudo apt-get install rtl-sdr soapysdr-module-rtlsdr`
but nothing seems to change the result.
When I compile and run the example (I added a print statement to output the number of Soapy SDR devices found) I get this:
gcc -std=c99 example.c  -lSoapySDR && ./a.out
Found 0 devicesSoapySDRDevice_make my fail: SoapySDR::Device::make() no match

Comment: When I run rtl_test I do get output: 
Found 1 device(s):
  0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
Detached kernel driver
Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
Supported gain values (29): 0.0 0.9 1.4 2.7 3.7 7.7 8.7 12.5 14.4 15.7 16.6 19.7 20.7 22.9 25.4 28.0 29.7 32.8 33.8 36.4 37.2 38.6 40.2 42.1 43.4 43.9 44.5 48.0 49.6